# Error installing gnome-shell-extension-common from AUR on Arch

Tags: arch-linux, gnome-shell

I'm new to Arch Linux and just wanted to theme my Gnome Shell by installing gnome-shell-extension-user-theme for the Gnome Tweak Tool. However I keep getting an error when trying to build gnome-shell-extension-common-git from AUR. The version number contains a hypen but if I edit the PKGBUILD it just gets written over again.

I run:

```
yaourt gnome-shell-extension-common-git
```

View contents of PKGBUILD:

```
# Maintainer: Alucryd <alucryd at gmail dot com>
# Contributor: Sebastian Lenz <sebastian@archusers.de>

pkgname=gnome-shell-extension-common-git
pkgver=3.8.1.7
pkgrel=1
pkgdesc="Common files for the GNOME Shell Extensions"
arch=('any')
url="http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Extensions"
license=('GPL' 'LGPL')
depends=('gnome-shell')
makedepends=('git' 'gnome-common' 'intltool')
provides=('gnome-shell-extension-common')
conflicts=('gnome-shell-extension-git' 'gnome-shell-extension-common')
source=('git+http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell-extensions#branch=gnome-3-8')
sha256sums=('SKIP')

pkgver() {
  cd "${srcdir}"/gnome-shell-extensions

  git describe | sed 's|\(.*-.*\)-.*|\1|;s|-|.|'
}

build() {
  cd "${srcdir}"/gnome-shell-extensions

  ./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr --disable-schemas-compile --enable-extensions=""
  make
}

package() {
  cd "${srcdir}"/gnome-shell-extensions

  make DESTDIR="${pkgdir}" install
}

# vim: ts=2 sw=2 et:
```

Get an error when building:

```
==> Starting pkgver()...
==> Updated version: gnome-shell-extension-common-git 3.8.3.1.real-2-1
==> ERROR: pkgver is not allowed to contain colons, hyphens or whitespace.
==> ERROR: Makepkg was unable to build gnome-shell-extension-common-git.
==> Restart building gnome-shell-extension-common-git ? [y/N]
```

New Contents of PKGBUILD:

```
# Maintainer: Alucryd <alucryd at gmail dot com>
# Contributor: Sebastian Lenz <sebastian@archusers.de>

pkgname=gnome-shell-extension-common-git
pkgver=3.8.3.1.real-2
pkgrel=1
pkgdesc="Common files for the GNOME Shell Extensions"
arch=('any')
url="http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Extensions"
license=('GPL' 'LGPL')
depends=('gnome-shell')
makedepends=('git' 'gnome-common' 'intltool')
provides=('gnome-shell-extension-common')
conflicts=('gnome-shell-extension-git' 'gnome-shell-extension-common')
source=('git+http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell-extensions#branch=gnome-3-8')
sha256sums=('SKIP')

pkgver() {
  cd "${srcdir}"/gnome-shell-extensions

  git describe | sed 's|\(.*-.*\)-.*|\1|;s|-|.|'
}

build() {
  cd "${srcdir}"/gnome-shell-extensions

  ./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr --disable-schemas-compile --enable-extensions=""
  make
}

package() {
  cd "${srcdir}"/gnome-shell-extensions

  make DESTDIR="${pkgdir}" install
}

# vim: ts=2 sw=2 et:
```

If I edit the file to remove the hypthen it makes no difference as it is added again when I try to build again.

Comment: Please leave a note on the AUR page so that the PKGBUILD maintainer updates the PKGBUILD with [Evan's fix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/82022/6761)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
git describe | sed 's|\(.*-.*\)-.*|\1|;s|-|.|'
```

to

```
git describe | sed 's|\(.*-.*\)-.*|\1|;s|-|.|g'
```

The package version originally had one hyphen in it. The version you are building has two hyphens. The `g` at the end of the `s` (substitute) command causes `sed` to substitute for multiple matches instead of just one.